# UTF-8 to C/POSIX locale conversion using iconv() fails

Tags: c, linux, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to convert UTF-8 string to C/POSIX locale string
The UTF-8 string is "abc123£" (in bash "abc123\302\243"`)

1. iconv_open("", "UTF-8"); // "" means default program locale i.e. C
2. iconv_open("UCS-2LE", "UTF-8");

iconv() is returning EILSEQ to me in case 1, but success in case 2.

What is the reason for this?
Also, how can I successfully convert any UTF-8 string to 'C' locale string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `C` locale uses a character set (probably US-ASCII) that doesn't have a character for `£`, and the string *can't* be converted without loss.

Comment: .. and the second call only succeeds because your input string  happens to contain just 16-byte UC characters (but it would fail on 32-bit characters).